# Report - show Accounts that changed status

Tags: reporting

I have a picklist field on my account
status: new, old, deferred

I want to run a report on accounts that were not of status 'old'  at the start of the period but are a 'old' at the end of the period.

I have started by creating a report on Accounts, but then realised that I have no idea how to see that transformation on an account.
Any ideas? Tia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to look at field history tracking:

> Modifying any of these fields adds a new entry to the History related
>   list. All entries include the date, time, nature of the change, and
>   who made the change. Note that not all field types are available for
>   history tracking. Certain changes, such as case escalations, are
>   always tracked

Note you have to proactively turn this on for the field you are interested in tracking changes to and you are limited to 20. Although Salesforce support can raise this with a request Case and justification.

The changes to the field can be shown on the page layout but are also available in an Account History report.

Account Page (related list):
[image]

Account History report:
[image]

The Salesforce help link:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history.htm&language=en_US